# How to configure content type and content encoding using glassfish server?

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, encoding, content-type

I am building a web application using JSF and Spring in eclipse indigo using Glassfish server 3.1.2 . Everything is going great but it is showing me this error in firebug in 2 JavaScript files[image].

When I check in those files I didn't find any illegal character in those files but firebug still showing this.
I have used these files in one of ASP.Net project and they didn't mess there so i checked and matched their content type from both projects then I found that in ASP.Net project these files have

## Content-Type = application/x-javascript

And in my JSP-Spring(JAVA) project there

## Content-Type = text/javascript;charset=ISO-8859-1

is this.So you can see that sames files have changed their content scheme. I found that this scheme can be change by configuration in glassfish server.So I want to change my JS files `content-Type` to same as in ASP type.
If anyone have any other solution then please share because I haven't found any solution other than changing the scheme from glassfish server
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those strange characters you are seeing is the UTF-8 [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). They are a special set of bytes that indicate how a document is encoded. Unfortunately, when interpreted as [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), you wind up with the problem you have. There are two ways to resolve this.

The first way is to change the output character set to UTF-8. I believe this can be done in your server configuration, in your [web.xml configuration](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.MimeMapping), or by setting the character set on the HTTP request object in code; for example: `yourServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`

The second way is to remove the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) from your Javascript files. You can do this by opening them in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), going to *Encoding* > *Convert to ANSI*, and then saving them. Alternatively, open them in Notepad, then go to *Save As* and ensure that the *Encoding* option is set to ANSI before saving them. Note that this may cause issues if you have non-[ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) text in your Javascript files, although this is unlikely.